# Can you give description for the third graph?

Tags: statistical-inference

[How Annual energy reduced while wind speed is increasing?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9AkW.jpg)

Comment: You can begin reading points 14 to 19 here http://www.wind-power-program.com/turbine_characteristics.htm and http://www.rpc.com.au/pdf/wind4.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are thinking that there should be more power output when the
wind blows faster. But the third graph doesn't show exactly that.

The *first* graph shows that about 10-11 m/sec. is the most common wind speed.
The third graph shows that the most energy is generated when wind blows 
about 12-13 m/sec. (even though that is a little above the most common wind speed).

Perhaps more to the point, the third graph shows that, on an annual basis, very little energy is generated when
the wind blows more than 25 m/sec. That's because the wind very seldom
blows that fast.

If you are interested in how energy output for a windmill increases with
wind speed, you need a graph that shows energy output per hour for one
windmill when the wind is blowing steadily at each of several wind speeds.
But the third graph doesn't show that. (The link provided by @cgiovanardi
does something like that.)